# Stochastic buffer buy n sell

Tags: mql5

i am try to get a stochastic buffer for an EA to take a sell position position crossing below the 20period and take a buy position crossing above the 20 period

if(cntBuy==0 && bufferMain[0]<=(100-InpUpperLevel) && bufferMain[1]>(100-InpUpperLevel))
expecting this to take a buy position crossing above the 20 period (21)

if(cntSell==0 && bufferMain[0]>=InpUpperLevel && bufferMain[1]<InpUpperLevel)
expecting this to take a sell position crossing below the 80period (79)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not got the logic correct for what you want to do. Try

`int InpUpperLevel=80;`

Buy:
`if(cntBuy==0 && bufferMain[0]>(100-InpUpperLevel) && bufferMain[1]<=(100-InpUpperLevel))`

Sell: `if(cntSell==0 && bufferMain[0]<InpUpperLevel && bufferMain[1]>=InpUpperLevel)`

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer if it has solved your problem, thanks.

Comment: what statement do i use to set a break even after it moves 5pips for risk management

Comment: Hi David, in order for stackoverflow to be effective, additional questions should be posted separately. Have a go at coding it yourself and if you run into problems, post the code and I'm sure you will receive help